# Connecting to IBM VPN on Android

Tags: android, networking, vpn

I feel like it must be possible to connect to the IBM VPN with Android using an L2TP/IPSec CRT VPN, but am not totally sure.  IBMers use the AT&T Global Network Connect Client that has integrated VPN management.  While this client is proprietary, I think the proprietary parts are the way it attempts internet connections, not really the VPN part.

Here are the VPN details reported by the Global Network Client:

```
Service: Managed VPN - IPSec DualAccess (default)
VPN Server IP address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
VPN Server type: AGN SIG
VPN Key Exchange Security: Diffie-Hellman Group 2
VPN Data Security: ESP,3DES,SHA1
VPN Data Compression: LZS
```

I can see during VPN connection where the client is verifying a certificate.  My guess is if I could find this certificate on the laptop, upload it to my SD card, and register the certificate on the Android, I could set up the connection successfully with a L2TP/IPSec CRT VPN.

Any idea where the client certificate could be found on the laptop?

Any takers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, on most Android smartphones, you can't do it as a user, because there aren't access to the settings that you need.

This has been discussed at length at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3902

Because it needs a change in the ROM, the only way around it for you is if you're willing to root your phone.

The only exception to this that I'm currently aware of is the Motorola Droid Pro, which has the necessary ROM modifications baked-in. There are a ton of articles around about it as Motorola made a bit of noise about it being the only Android to include support for Cisco IPSec - e.g. http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/207556/new_droid_pro_security_features_lead_the_way.html